# Assigning variable to Snowflake SQL based on condition

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to execute a sql command based on input variable passed as parameter in Stored Procedure. If the parameter passed was INCR, I would like to append a part of the sql to final sql query variable.

```
var exec_cmnd = (load_type == 'INCR') ? "AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl T WHERE inner_tbl.id = outer_tbl.id)" : "1 = 1";  

var qry = "`select * from tbl_a where name=name and `+exec_cmnd+`";

snowflake.execute({sqlText:qry});
```

But the condition seem to throw an error. Please let me know how i can assign a variable to a sql command query variable based on IF condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `load_type` is passed into the stored procedure, you need to uppercase it in the body of the JavaScript.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#case-sensitivity-in-javascript-arguments

Your concatenation is off slightly. I highly recommend using JavaScript literal templates for SQL in JavaScript stored procedures.

Open your string with a back tick and close with a back tick. You can then replace any JavaScript variable by wrapping it like this: ${myVariable}. It also allows you to use single and double quotes and multi-line statements in your SQL without issues.

```
create or replace procedure foo(load_type string)
returns string
language javascript
as
$$

var exec_cmnd = (LOAD_TYPE == 'INCR') ? "EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl T WHERE inner_tbl.id = outer_tbl.id)" : "1 = 1";  

var qry = `select * from tbl_a where name=name and ${exec_cmnd}`;

return qry;

$$;

call foo('INCR');
```